# Could curl download an image in remote url into cache, then use pipeline to convert it?

Tags: shell, curl, imagemagick, pipeline, imagemagick-convert

I have some image urls, I want to download them. But these files have different suffix, such as `.jpg`, `.png` or `.bmp`. I also want to change them into a unified format, such as `.JPEG`. So I want to use the `curl` command to download the image into the memory cache, then use the `convert` command in `ImageMagick` package to convert the data format into `.JPEG` format. Is there a method to do this work?

```
    `curl http://aa.com/a.jpg`
    `convert a.jpg 00001.JPEG`
    `rm a.jpg`
    `curl http://bb.com/b.png`
    `convert b.png 00002.JPEG`
    `rm b.png`
```

I want to simplify this procedure, let the temp files save into cache, then not save into the disk directly, so lessen the burden of the disk.
Is there any way to use `pipeline` technology to do this work? such as

```
    `curl http://aa.com/a.jpg | convert ... | ...`
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
curl http://aa.com/a.jpg | convert - 00001.jpeg
curl http://bb.com/b.jpg | convert - 00002.jpeg
```

The file are then in JPEG format:

```
user@host:~# file 00001.jpeg
file.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
user@host:~# file 00002.jpeg
file.jpeg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

That's it.

Comment: Another alternative: use ImageMagick directly since it supports [HTTP](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#read). So `convert http://example.com/a.png 00001.jpeg` does the trick.

Comment: @deltheil, really true! It's more simple. Thanks.